# As 10/20K+, what moderation task helps most?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities, community-moderation

As 10K+ (actually 20K+, but that makes a rather small difference), there are several ways to help out with moderation.

- Close Votes
- Reopen Votes
- Low Quality Posts
- Suggested Edits
- First Posts
- Late Answers
- Highest/lowest voted questions/answers
- (Possibly more, please edit and add to the list).

If I have 10 minutes to spare, doing some moderation tasks, **what moderation task should I focus on that provides most value to the community and most help to the ♦ moderators?**

I'd guess that focusing on the tasks that I have access to that requires the highest reputation is a good start, as there are more people that can help out with the tasks that require lower reputation.

Comment: Look at the numbers in the top-bar and take the biggest one.

Comment: **Any** action that keeps a post / flag / whatever from reaching the moderators helps. After that, any action that makes the job of the moderator *easier* helps (research duplicate answer flags, tell moderators that a post can be merged based on them, etc.).

Comment: Polls like this are no more appropriate on meta than they are on the main site.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a poll-question, @Servy.

Comment: @Servy I don't think that it is a poll. I do expect the ♦ moderators to be able to come up with a distinctive answer on where their job burden hurts most and help is most appreciated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How is this any different than, "What programming language should I learn?", from the point of view of on-topicness here?

Comment: @AndersAbel It's not really an answerable question.  Different moderators (and site users) are doing different things, have different opinions as to what actions are more important for the health of the site, as well as how much effort different actions take.  Furthermore these things are constantly changing over time as moderation tools evolve, as new problems arise or go away in questions, etc.  The question just isn't really answerable, any more than, as I said earlier, "What is the best programming language for met to learn?"

Comment: @Servy: This is *meta*, we can hash out policy or guidance here. The OP is not asking for everyone to chime in with their experiences here.

Comment: @Servy: The number of things is limited enough. I can imagine an authoritative answer from a community manager or moderator that would be broadly applicable here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Whether or not that's what he wants, that's what it's almost certainly going to end up becoming, just as with my analogy.  When someone asks what programming langauge to learn they want one person to answer with a bunch of detailed information explaining a list of options, benefits/drawbacks, and making an argument for some conclusively best option.  What they get is a bunch of people saying, "pick mine!".

Comment: @Servy: Let me reiterate again then that this is *Meta*; we *do* allow more subjective subjects. Fewer people come here, and there is no reputation to be earned either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There are *dozens* of possible moderation actions that such users are capable of doing.  The exmaples in the question are just touching the surface.  There's also edits, tag cleanups, voting, all sorts of queries you can write yourself to find problematic content, just trolling through the questions list looking for stuff to fix, etc.  And everyone, even moderators, are going to have varying opinions on how much each possible action helps.  There is no real way to objectively state which option is "best".

Comment: @Servy is correct, and you will also get moderator biased answers. Mod A might find researching duplicate posts tedious and not do it much, where mod B might find reviewing suggested edits onerous. Plus, the OP also said "Add as you see fit" which invites open ended lists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is a somewhat higher tolerance for subjectivity than SO, yes, but that doesn't mean there still isn't such a thing as "too subjective".

Comment: @AndersAbel - "I don't think that it is a poll. I do expect the ♦ moderators to be able to come up with a distinctive answer on where their job burden hurts most and help is most appreciated." - Doesn't that make it primarily opinion based?

Comment: @Servy: Sure, there are too subjective topics that are not worth our time discussing. *This post is not such a post*. There are a limited number of moderators, we have votes, it'll be fine.

Comment: @JohnP: Discussion on Meta is *mostly* opinion! That's the point of the tag, and of Meta, really, to form consensus around certain opinions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But it is for opinions that have some basis in fact/evidence.  This question is going to invite answers that are backed simply by a mod stating what they find most annoying, rather than incorporating any real evidence behind an opinion.

Comment: I wish more 10/20K users would stop to ask this sometimes!

Comment: @Servy: As long as it is not a poll question **that is fine by me**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But that *is* a poll question.  Even if you limit the scope of the poll to mods (which, by the way, it doesn't) there are still hundreds of mods.

Comment: @Servy: there are **seventeen** Stack Overflow mods. And we are asking them to build a consensus, and we can vote on that. Can we just at least see how this one pans out?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even if you get one, it becomes obsolete in a matter of weeks.  You end up with a "consensus" as to some problem because it has poor tooling around it, so SE goes and improves the tooling around that problem, and a year from now you end up with people over-emphasizing that tool to the point that they're adding little value because "it's the most important moderation action".

Comment: I don't think the fact that consensus changes over time invalidates attempting to derive the current consensus as long as everyone involved understands it's fluid and doesn't try to build dogma on it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Triage on the tricky bits that need moderator attention would win it for me. Ideally as a moderator I'd like to be picking up an issue with some of the background work done, which would be a massive time saver.

Examples:

1. Better spam spotting for NAA/VLQ flagged posts.

   Again this is a background checking thing: people that use the [advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106579/153020) and explain what/how they found a bigger problem are exceedingly helpful.

   Checking out the user's public profile information to see if it connects them to the domain in question can transform "possible spam" into "definitely a problem" with a little bit of detective work.

   It's surprising how often an NAA/VLQ flagged post is actually someone clearly astroturfing that doesn't get spotted.
2. Use delete votes without picking up the red batphone - plenty of 20K+ users instinctively hit flag->other for issues that could trivially be fixed by the community without needing a moderator. Even if it doesn't get fixed by the community up front it's nice to get someone else's name next to a moderators because that sends a clear message that it isn't just a mean moderator acting unilaterally.

There are other weird things to look out for too, particularly in late answers. For example a user who suddenly unaccepts a long standing accepted answer and then accepts a crappy/plagiarised answer posted in the last hour or so from a new, low rep user is 99% of the time going to be into sockpuppeting and worth raising a flag about.

In short: use your powers and experience to do the stuff that lots of reviewers simply can't or haven't got the experience of.