# As 3K+, what moderation task helps most?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-abilities, community-moderation

I'm blatantly creating a derivative work of the question [As 10/20K+, what moderation task helps most?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251220/as-10-20k-what-moderation-task-helps-most), which is a great question for the 21,943 users at that level. I, along with 58,240 other users, have reached 3K but have not yet achieved the reputation level relevant for the answer to that question to be applicable.

As 3K+ to 9999 rep user, there are several ways to help out with moderation.

The [Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) are obviously a good place to start.  But looking at the stats, the "reviews today" exceeds the "need review" value in all but the close vote queue, indicating there are ample members of the community keeping up with all but the close vote queue. So after tending to close votes, it's less clear.

One can also flag, upvote/downvote, edit, edit/create tag usage guidance, or exercise one of the most powerful moderation tools, [post on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268115/1161484).

The [Moderation Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) have helpful targets for users new to moderation, and provide good moderation training in the process of achieving them.  But after achieving these goals, I'm motivated to be as helpful as I can to the community.  I've reviewed questions asked of candidates in recent moderator elections for priorities that appear to be of value, but the level of commitment for moderator candidates seems to be higher.

If I have 10-30 minutes to spare, doing some moderation tasks, **what moderation task should I focus on that provides the most value to the community and most help to the ♦ moderators?**

Some more specific fine tuning questions:

- Is using close votes in the First Posts or Triage queues more helpful, or less because it adds to the CV queue (but still removes close-able posts from the site)?
- Given a limited number of downvotes, is there a strategy to using them on posts more likely to feed the Roomba?
- Given a limited number of flags, does adding a NAA flag to a post someone else has already flagged have any value at all or is it better to conserve that flag for a more deserving target?

Comment: related: [How can I best help with Close Votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285454/839601)

Comment: I'd suggest following some tags you're interested in and keeping an eye out for questions that need fixing or closing there.  Or filter your reviews by tags, so it gets less mind-numbing than seeing questions about languages and frameworks you have no interest in or knowledge about.  i.e. review in ways you can do well at.

Comment: @PeterCordes pardon my ignorance but how do you _filter your reviews by tags_ ?

Comment: [Allow wildcard \[tag\*\] filters in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362543) shows an image of where the filter thing is in the review UI.

Comment: Just a minor thing but this question is a bit open to opinion. I would specify a bit more what you mean by helpful? What aspect of the curation do you personally find most important or least important? What do you enjoy (we need you staying happy doing the stuff)? There may not be a universally accepted most helpful action.

Comment: Eliminate crap in the VtC, **but without becoming a robo-closer**... and help users of the unfairly closed questions to get a reopen.

Comment: @peterh I don't feel individual close votes generally make much of an impact. They often end up expiring, except for very new questions that generally don't have much of a problem getting closed anyway. There's also a mountain of questions in the close vote queue, which is only as small as it is because they're quite generous with making votes expire (which doesn't exactly help with making votes feel impactful). Admittedly, however, if everyone "does their part", these probably won't be problems. Although there are also a number of systematic changes that could fix or alleviate these problems.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I remember as I was a beginner here. The typical rationality of the robo-closers is that the users don't listen. But... I did. I fought for my questions. I did everything what I could. And I got the closures. Again and again. And I never forgot it. That is all. Meanwhile, I've also understood that many robo-closers (robo-downers, robo-deleters) are driven by actually an irrational hostile urge and not an urge to make the site better.

Comment: @peterh Just to clarify: my comment was about my reasoning behind not participating in close voting (much, any more), not about robo-closing (which most likely does more harm than good).

Comment: You can use [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to identify posts you can delete with a single downvote (I'm sure there's a script somewhere on there that does that already). Although these are posts that basically no-one is seeing anyway, so they're not really doing much harm.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Some of those posts are also useful, despite that they are closed. Some have answers in Answers, others in comments. I sometimes fear that they are downvoted just to be deleted, which in my opinion isn't the right thing to do.

Comment: For me the most impactful action would probably be to make a substantial edit to turn a mediocre or bad post into a good one. Although this is more something you stumble across than something you can search for. Unless you can identify some common easily-searchable issues (but those probably wouldn't affect the quality of a post too much).

Comment: @Scratte If the post seems useful, you should upvote it instead of downvoting it. But yes, a potential problem with Roomba in general (and especially with intentionally triggering it) is deleting an obscure issue that someone would've found useful at some point in the future.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I do upvote posts I find useful. But then maybe all they have is just this one vote of mine. Someone else finding posts to delete just from a SEDE query, can undo that in an instant, no? What I mean to say is: Use is conscientiously :)

Comment: @BernhardBarker using queries like that IMO is an abuse of the Roomba system, the Roomba isn't a personal deletion vigilante. 1 non-mod user shouldn't be able to singlehandedly delete another user's post. There's nothing wrong with keeping obscure posts on the site, people generally don't cruise questions upvoting everything useful anymore. Well scoped low activity questions will show up only under very specific Google searches and not bother anyone who isn't looking for them, users must have restraint to let it go when they're just not interested in something, maybe somebody else is.

Comment: Close voting is not everything. Instead of concentrating on removing bad content, you could also help improve good content, for example improve existing good questions and answers by editing or voting on all answers (and if it's only improving the language).

Comment: Always upvote good content and downvote bad content when you see it organically (e.g. in passing/browsing around the site), completely separate from this. Voting in all forms is important.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The most helpful is probably to review close votes on posts with tags where you have domain expertise, regardless of your SO rep. These can often not get reviewed by the average user, since they tend to be too technical. Such directed close-vote reviews is particularly helpful for low traffic tags.

If you click the review queue icon, then pick *Close Votes* review queue, there is a filter option you can use for this:

[image]

---

Type in whatever tags that apply. In the above example I used [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) - which is a high traffic tag, so it should probably be combined with some more niche tag. And if you are going through a low-traffic niche tag and need additional votes to help close something, you can ask for back up through the [SO Close Vote Reviewers Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (where you can also ask for help with reviewing/user moderation in general).

If you don't feel confident enough to label yourself expert in any kind of technology, there's always the various regular reviews. Suggested edits is particularly important (IMO) since bad edits can be very harmful & that queue in particular always had problems with "robo-reviewers", which need to be countered with real reviewers.

Comment: The fact that there is a _Filter_ available was pointed out to me when visiting the CloseVoteChat - after about 2y of casuallly doing reviews. Somehow the link never **popped** out to me.

Comment: The filter has been pointed to me and it took me a minute to see it. That interface defninitely needs a free hand red circle or something.